# Alternative to implementing IEnumerable<T> and converting each element?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, type-conversion

I have a data class, which wraps a collection of objects, because I want to manage access to them in a special way. Naturally, it makes sense to implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so that clients can iterate the data.

In my special case, however, it doesn't make sense to iterate over each element directly, instead it would be helpful to iterate and convert each entry like the following.

**A**

```
public class GameMap : IEnumerable<Vector>
{
    private TileType[,] grid;

    public IEnumerator<Vector> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // I never want to iterate all tile types on my map,
        // but I do want to get each coordinate as a vector struct.
        for (int y = 0; y < grid.GetLength(0); y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(1); x++)
                yield return new Vector(x, y);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // This smells of bad design...
        // How should client code know that these elements need to be cast to Vector?
        return grid.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

To restate, I do need to keep my TileType collection as a data source, but I also want to iterate over a collection of vector coordinates. Should I maybe ditch this implementation in favor of explicitly named methods like in this version?

**B**

```
public class GameMap
{
    private TileType[,] grid;

    // Keep the enumerable, but not the enumerator.
    public IEnumerable<Vector> GetEnumerable()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < grid.GetLength(0); y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(1); x++)
                yield return new Vector(x, y);
    }

    // Or just pass in another method.
    public void Iterate(Action<Vector> action)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < grid.GetLength(0); y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(1); x++)
                action.Invoke(new Vector(x, y));
    }
}
```

`TileType` in this case is an enum, needed to build other objects, like a graph representation. `Vector` is a simple struct, which generally makes sense. At least when following common game engine design, where some kind of coordinate/point tuple is needed thousands of times. As I understand it, it makes more sense to quickly create structs than to cache/pool them as class types.

As a main design goal, I would like to avoid code duplication, which I have a lot of because client code iterates over the coordinates of my grid in a nested for loop and does something with the coordinates. I could consolidate all that duplicate looping into a single method call, if it were a member of the `GameMap` type.

---

After reading some of the comments: My question can be rephrased like this:

**Requirements**

- Store a collection of TileType objects.
- Iterate over all Vector structs which represent all map coordinates.
- Access specific tile information via a get-method that takes x and y coordinates.

For now, it is convenient for clients to be able to call

```
foreach(Vector coord in gameMap)
```

because it is easy to understand and shorter than

```
foreach(Vector coord in gameMap.GetVectors())
```

This is why I chose to implement `IEnumerable<Vector>`. So far, I wouldn't need to ask, I could just go on with it, because it works.

But: Soon I might discover that I also need to iterate TileType objects are maybe add other data to my GameMap class. Now I have a discrepancy, because I can (or at least should because of convenience) only implement one type of `GetEnumerator()`. In this case, is there any framework guideline or convention, that might be stating "Implement `IEnumerable` for the data type specific to the collection the object is representing" or is it also common practice to use `IEnumerable` for the most convenient option to the user?

Comment: You realize both functions in example B will lead to the same result? It will iterate all elements in both dimensions.

Comment: In A why are you returning `grid.GetEnumerator()` instead of just `GetEnumerator()` which would call your first function?

Comment: @Gusman: That's probably intentional. One returns an `IEnumerable<Vector>`, the other one invokes a method on each element.

Comment: @Gusman: Yes, those are just two similar examples of how to implement my desired behaviour differently, asking if you guys think it makes more sense than implementing IEnumerable via the enumerator.

Comment: Unless you explain the exact behavior you want we can't suppose anything. Also, why use an enumerator or an Iterate function? just have two properties `X` and `Y` which return the dimensions of the array and use those as you want, no need to create all those vectors at all.

Comment: @gbishop3: I probably could, but this doesn't change my design problem, or does it? Calling code would need to cast each element to Vector, but the GameMap class wraps a TileType collection. This seems like a violation of catering to expectations. Maybe I am overthinking though.

Comment: @Gusman: My goal is to reduce code duplication across my client projects. I have a dozen methods which have a nested for loop, create a vector, look up some cached data or set some fields, but they could all do it via the vector iterator in two lines.

Comment: Then, instead of creating on the fly each time those vectors, why don't you create on the class a vector array and instantiate all the vectors you need only once when the grid is assigned?

Comment: @Gusman Presumably the *other* operations that the class performs need the underlying implementation to be the tile types, and the reverse conversion would need to be done if you did that.

Comment: @Servy Sorry but I don't understand you, the enumerator returns vectors and those are constructed based only on the grid dimensions. Maybe I ddin't explained well, I don't mean to remove the grid info or any other thing, just to add a property `Vector[] Vectors` which is filled when the grid is set, then the user can iterate that property, use a concrete item from there or anything he wants, that would be a lot more efficient as the vectors are instantiated only once.

Comment: @Gusman That assumes that creating the vectors is expensive, an assumption unlikely to be true, it requires a significant memory footprint increase of the program over the OP's program, it only ever has *potential* improvements if the type is iterated multiple times, which may or may not be the case, etc.  Yes, there may be circumstances in which that could be preferable, but it's also quite likely that it'd be *worse*, particularly considering that if a given caller wants to iterate this data multiple times they can simply store the results in a collection themselves, if that's needed.

Comment: @Servy It's not an assumption, from the user comments: `I have a dozen methods which have a nested for loop, create a vector, look up some cached data or set some fields, but they could all do it via the vector iterator in two lines`

Comment: @Gusman That doesn't tell you if they're all iterating the same object instances or separate object instances, but regardless, most of my points still stand.  Even if it *is* all iterating one object instance (something you don't know for sure) the current method will still use half the memory, is unlikely to be meaningfully slower, and can still be cached by callers if it would be appropriate.

Comment: Which is true: a game map *is* a sequence of vectors, or a game map *has* a sequence of vectors?  A car is not a collection of tires; a car *has* a collection of tires. This should inform your decision. A map *has* a collection of vectors, it *has* a collection of tiles, it *has* a collection of edges, it *has* a collection of submaps, whatever. So make each of those methods, not interfaces.

Comment: What is shorter to type is irrelevant. No one is going to die younger because they had to type `.Vectors()`.

Answer (score -1):

> Should I maybe ditch this implementation in favor of explicitly named methods like in this version?

Yes, but not in the way you show.

If your `GameMap` class is supposed to be understood as a "collection of [tile] objects", better do not offer an `IEnumerable<T>` implementation on it that enumerates anything other than tiles.
Otherwise, it will simply not be clear what is being retrieved in statements such as

```
foreach (var item in myGameMap)
```

For that reason, to enumerate anything other than tile objects, call your member (which could also be a property rather than a method) in such a way that it describes what it returns - e.g. `AsVectors`, `GetTileVectors`, etc.

---

Furthermore, note that while you say

> it doesn't make sense to iterate over each element directly

iterating "over each element" is only the most straightfoward thing that can be done with an `IEnumerable<T>`.
Counting based upon some condition, mapping the tiles in some way, or finding a specific tile might still be relevant operations, so implementing `IEnumerable<TileType>` right on your `GameMap` class may still make some sense.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145814/discussion-on-answer-by-o-r-mapper-alternative-to-implementing-ienumerablet).